# How to load Database data in Zend Form Form Element Select?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I am trying to load the dynamic data from databse to the following zend form element. How to do that i have no idea.

```
$this->add(array(
                'type'  => 'Select',
                'name' => 'catid',
                'attributes' => array(
                    'id' =>'catid'
                 ),
                 'options' => array(
                         'label' => 'Category',
                         'value_options' => array(
                                 '1' => 'Action',
                                 '2' => 'Comedy',
                                 '3' => 'Sci-Fi',
                                 '4' => 'Drama',
                         ),
                 )
        ));
```

I want to add dynamic values to :

```
                                    '1' => 'Action',
                                     '2' => 'Comedy',
                                     '3' => 'Sci-Fi',
                                     '4' => 'Drama',
```

Comment: [google: zend form element select database value](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=zend%20form%20element%20select%20database%20data)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following codes :P

```
$form = new Zform('zform');
$form->get('catid')->setValueOptions($options);
```